# Page not found when clicking on pagination tab

Tags: pagination

I have a category page and I am getting some issues on pagination. When I click on NEXT PAGE then I am getting

> Oops! That page can’t be found.

[image]

and the URL is showing `http://example.com/category/accessories/page/2/` which is correct.

Below is my full code which is I am using on the category page.

```
<?php
   /**
   * A Simple Category Template
   */
get_header(); 
?>  
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
   <main id="main" class="site-main">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="equalPadding"> 
   <?php 
  global $paged;
  $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
  $args = array('posts_per_page' => 6,'paged'=> $paged,); 
  $tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );
       if ($tyler_query->have_posts()){
          if(is_category()){          
                 $category_images = get_option( 'category_images' );
                 $category_image = '';
                 if ( is_array( $category_images ) && array_key_exists( get_query_var('cat'), $category_images ) ){
                 $category_image = $category_images[get_query_var('cat')] ;
                 ?>        
            <div class="category-img" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $category_image;?>)">
            <div class="category_heading d-flex related-post">
            <div class="cp-heading"><h1><?php single_cat_title(''); ?></h1></div>
        <?php   //check if category is a subcategory

    if( 0 != $this_category->parent ){ //if subcategory then display feature post
         //displaying feature post here
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3,'meta_key' => '_featured-post','meta_value' => 1);
    $featured = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($featured->have_posts()):?><div class="subCat_featurePost post-list ">
            <?php while($featured->have_posts()): $featured->the_post();?>
            <div class="item"> <div class="thumb"><a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a></div>
             <div class="title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute('echo=0'));?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 16, '...');?></a></div></div>
              <?php endwhile;?></div><?php else:
    endif;
    }?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } } ?>
      <div class="categoryWrapper_list cp-seeWrapper">
            <div class="row">
       <?php $index = 0;
            $check=0;
//Main category list displaying from here
        while ($tyler_query->have_posts()){
           $tyler_query->the_post();
     if ($index < 4) {?>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">  
        <div class="row spaceBottom cp-shadow bg-white cp-homeRelated">
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding0">
        <div class="cp-homeRelatedImg"><a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
       </div>
          </div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 colcentertext">
        <div class="marginautoWrapper">
        <?php $category = get_queried_object();
              if ( ! empty( $category ) ) {
              $cat_list='<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
               }?>
        <div class="d-flex cp-CategoryList">
                <div class="seeDate"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y');?></div>
                <div class="cp_cat_list"><?php echo $cat_list;?></div>
              </div>
          <div class="cp-b-content">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute('echo=0'));?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 16, '...');?></a></h2>
<p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 35, '...');?></p>
            <h5>By <span><?php the_author(); ?></span></h5>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
    </div>
      <?php  } else {
        if ($check==0){?>
         <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding0"><div class="row">
      <?php $check=1;}?>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="cp-shadow cp-seeSinglePostWrapper">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute('echo=0'));?>" class=""><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
            <div class="bg-white single-post-box">
              <div class="d-flex cp-CategoryList">
                <div class="seeDate"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y');?></div>
                <div class="cp_cat_list"><?php echo $cat_list;?></div>

              </div>
              <div class="cp-b-content">
                <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute('echo=0'));?>" class=""><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 12, '...');?></a>
                </h2>
                  <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 25, '...');?></p>
              <h5>By <span><?php the_author(); ?></span></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
           <?php   } $index++;}?></div></div>

  <?php if ($index > 4) {?>
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="cp-social cp-shadow bg-white">
        <h3>Social</h3>
           <?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer-social')) :
                 dynamic_sidebar('footer-social');
                endif;
      ?>
  </div>
    <div class="cp-newsletter cp-shadow bg-white">
         <?php  if (is_active_sidebar('cp_newsletter')) :
                 dynamic_sidebar('cp_newsletter');
                endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
       <?php } ?>
  <div class="cp-postPagination">
     <div class="nav-previous cp-pagi float-left"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
       <div class="nav-next cp-pagi float-right"><?php next_posts_link( null, $tyler_query->max_num_pages ); ?> </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
    <?php } else{?><p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p><?php } ?>


         </div>
      </div>
   </main>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First thing:

Category archives default to using this permalink/URL structure:

```
http://example.com/category/<category slug>/ (for page #1)
http://example.com/category/<category slug>/page/<page number>/ (for page #2, #3, and so on)
```

So when you visit `http://example.com/category/accessories/page/2/`, WordPress will automatically make a call to `WP_Query` and the parameters being used are retrieved from the current page URL:

```php
WP_Query( array(
  'category_name' => 'accessories', // the <category slug> in the URL
  'paged'         => 2,             // the <page number> in the URL
) );
```

And that is the main query.

**So when the `paged` value is *greater than* the max number of pages for *the main query*, then a `404` error page would be displayed.** And in your case, does the category `accessories` actually have enough number of posts for the archive page to have a page #2? I bet no.

### Second thing:

Category templates should just display posts retrieved via the *main query*:

```php
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    // Display the post.
}
```

But I'm not seeing that anywhere in your code.

### Third thing:

You can use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query by modifying its parameters:

```php
// This should go in your theme's functions.php file.
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    // Set the number of posts per page to 6, but only on category archives.
    if ( ! $query->is_admin && $query->is_main_query() && is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
    }
} );
```

Then in your code, there's no necessity for this:

```php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 6,'paged'=> $paged,);
$tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args ); // secondary query
```

Additionally:

1. Change the `$tyler_query->have_posts()` to `have_posts()`.
2. Then change the `$tyler_query->the_post()` to `the_post()`.
3. Just use `<?php next_posts_link(); ?>` without having to pass the max number of pages (the `$tyler_query->max_num_pages` in your code).

Comment: Yes, I have while ( have_posts() ) { in my answer but  I am using like                   while ($tyler_query->have_posts()){ in my answer.

Comment: Check the updated answer and do let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I checked your previous answer, and it was working. I added some code (which you shared pre_get_posts)in function.php and remove the WP_Query code and change the next_posts_link.

Comment: In that case, then you can accept that answer and/or upvote it.. :)

Comment: Yes, It's working...upvote from my side.

Comment: can you help me out with this issue? Is this possible with custom code? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/382964/hook-event-for-upload-image-in-the-menu