# Hook event for upload image in the menu

Tags: plugin-development, images, menus, hooks, admin-menu

I have to add the image in my dropdown. I know I can do this with `CSS Classes (optional)` but I don't want to do this. I want to add dynamically instead of open the code and change or add it.

What I am doing is, I have my products and I have to add my products to the dropdown menu along with the product image and heading.

My expectation dropdown output

[image]

I don't want to use any plugin. I need a custom code to solve this issue. I am using the below code. would you help me out with this?

```
//hook event for upload image on menu
function add_image_on_menu_module()
{
    // Add these actions for  add
    add_action('create_menu', 'save_image');
    add_action('menu_add_form_fields', 'add_image_menu');//display image upload option on menu
}
add_action('init', 'add_image_on_menu_module');

//display image upload option 
function add_image_menu($tag)
{
    $menu_image = get_option('menu_image');
    $menu_img = '';
    if (is_array($menu_image) && array_key_exists($tag->term_id, $menu_image)) {
        $menu_img = $menu_image[$tag->term_id];
    }
    ?>
    <div>
        <p><label>Image</label></p>
        <p>
            <?php
                if ($menu_img != "") {
                    ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $menu_img; ?>" alt="" title=""  style="width:300px;"  />
            <?php
                }
                ?>
            <br />
            <!-- Add this html here -->
            <input type="text" class="regular-text" id="custom_menu_image" name="menu_image" value="<?php echo $menu_img; ?>">
            <button class="set_menu_image button">Set Image url</button>
        </p>
    </div>

<?php
}


function save_image($term_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['menu_image'])) {
        //load existing category featured option
        $menu_image = get_option('menu_image');
        //set featured post ID to proper category ID in options array
        $menu_image[$term_id] =  $_POST['menu_image'];
        //save the option array
        update_option('menu_image', $menu_image);
    }
}


// Enquey media elements
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    if (is_admin())
        wp_enqueue_media();
});

// Add JS using admin_footer or enque thorugh hooks
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_footer_scripts');
function my_footer_scripts()
{
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            if (jQuery('.set_menu_image').length > 0) {
                if (typeof wp !== 'undefined' && wp.media && wp.media.editor) {
                    jQuery('.set_menu_image').on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var button = jQuery(this);
                        var url_input = jQuery("#custom_menu_image");
                        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                            url_input.val(attachment.url);
                        };
                        wp.media.editor.open(button);
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
 ?>
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Which code/part isn't giving you the expected outcome?

Comment: @SallyCJ, I have to add the products to the dropdown menu so I added them as normally as we are adding the menu. Now my boss told me that I have to add the product image too. So how can I add the product image? I can't use the class option because images are dynamically

Comment: "the dropdown menu" - you mean `wp_nav_menu()`? Can you show the code you used to display that dropdown?

Comment: @SallyCJ, I think, My issue got resolved, I have a create a custom text called the shop and once the user clicks on shop then it will display the dropdown.  What I did, I added a shortcode to display all the products  in the dropdown <?php  echo do_shortcode ("[products orderby='date']"); // this is the woocommerce shortcode?> and I am getting my expected output

Comment: Good for you then, but you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119583/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-naren-verma).